# How can i get my function to repeat until i get a valid input

Tags: python

#This is my code and i want my function to loop until i get an answer between 1-10 but don't know how to do it.

```
n = int(input("skriv ett nummer mellan 1-10"))

def func(n , minn, maxn):
    while n < minn:
        n = int(input("Ange ett nytt nummer, detta var för lågt"))
    if maxn < n:
        n = int(input("ange ett nytt nummer, detta var för högt"))
    else:
        print(n)
    return "Detta var ett bra nummer"

a = func(n, 1, 10)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details ?

Comment: when the person writes a number greater than 10 or less than 1 it asks for a new number but it doesn't check to see if the new number meets the conditions or not. The program just shuts down after asking for a new number if the number was not in the range between 1-10

Comment: I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#use this.

```
def func(n , minn, maxn):
    while True:
        if n < minn:
            n = int(input("Ange ett nytt nummer, detta var för lågt"))
            continue
        elif maxn < n:
            n = int(input("ange ett nytt nummer, detta var för högt"))
            continue
        else:
            print(n)
            return "Detta var ett bra nummer"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def test_range(n, min, max):
    while (n not in range(min,max+1)):
        n = int(input("Input should be between "+str(min)+" and "+str(max)+" value "))
test_range(10,1,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it:

```
def func(minn, maxn):
    n = int(input("Ange ett nytt nummer, detta var för lågt: "))
    while n not in range(minn,maxn+1):
        n = int(input("Ange ett nytt nummer, detta var för lågt: "))
    else:
        print(n)
        return "Detta var ett bra nummer"
func(1,10)
```